# sql conf nullpointer parquet

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am pretty new to Spark Echo system trying to write data from CSV to parquet but fails with NullPointerException. Not sure what I am missing.

```
case class PdRecordData(id: String, dates: String, dayOfWeek: String,      pdDistrict: String,address: String, longitude: String, latitude: String)

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext.createParquetFile[PdRecordData]("C:\\AS\\Parquet", true, new   Configuration()).registerTempTable("PdRegistry")
val csvFile = sc.textFile("C:\\AS\\crimeratedata\\samplefromorg.csv")
val rowsWithHeader = csvFile.map { x => x.split(",").map { _.trim } }
val maps = rowsWithHeader.map { case Array(id,dates, dayOfWeek, pdDistrict, address, longitude, latitude) => PdRecordData(id,dates, dayOfWeek, pdDistrict, address, longitude, latitude) }
maps.foreach { x => sqlContext.sql("INSERT INTO PdRegistry SELECT " +  "'" + x.dates + "','" + x.dayOfWeek + "','" + x.pdDistrict + "','" + x.address + "','" + x.longitude + "','" + x.latitude + "'")}
```

Throws the following exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLConf$class.getConf(SQLConf.scala:175)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.getConf(SQLContext.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLConf$class.dialect(SQLConf.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.dialect(SQLContext.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:302)
```

Comment: One thing I have done is use [Apache Drill][1] to create my parquet files from CSVs and then after that use the parquet files within Apache Spark jobs via Spark SQL.  Loading CSV to Parquet files with Apache Drill is VERY easy.


  [1]: https://drill.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(maps)
sqlContext.write.parquet(path)
```